# What does `(i & (i + 1)) - 1` mean? (in Fenwick Trees)

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, bit-manipulation, fenwick-tree

While learning about Fenwick Trees, I found this implementation:

Source: https://algorithmist.com/wiki/Fenwick_tree

```
class Fenwick_Tree_Sum
{
    vector<int> tree;
    Fenwick_Tree_Sum(const vector<int>& Arg)//Arg is our array on which we are going to work
    {
        tree.resize(Arg.size());
        
        for(int i = 0 ; i<tree.size(); i++)
            increase(i, Arg[i]);
        
    }

    // Increases value of i-th element by ''delta''.
    void increase(int i, int delta)
    {
        for (; i < (int)tree.size(); i |= i + 1)
            tree[i] += delta;
    }

    // Returns sum of elements with indexes left..right, inclusive; (zero-based);
    int getsum(int left, int right)
    {
        return sum(right) - sum(left-1); //when left equals 0 the function hopefully returns 0
    }

    int sum(int ind)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        while (ind>=0)
        {
            sum += tree[ind];
            ind &= ind + 1;
            ind--;
        }
        return sum;
    }
};
```

I can see `i |= i + 1` and `ind &= ind + 1; ind--` in the code.

I know that `i |= i + 1` just sets the next unset bit.

But, what does `(i & (i + 1)) - 1` actually do?

Here are some examples:

```
-------------------------------------
         i        | (i & (i + 1)) - 1
-------------------------------------
  0 - 0000000000  |  -1 - 1111111111
  1 - 0000000001  |  -1 - 1111111111
  2 - 0000000010  |   1 - 0000000001
  3 - 0000000011  |  -1 - 1111111111
  4 - 0000000100  |   3 - 0000000011
  5 - 0000000101  |   3 - 0000000011
  6 - 0000000110  |   5 - 0000000101
  7 - 0000000111  |  -1 - 1111111111
  8 - 0000001000  |   7 - 0000000111
  9 - 0000001001  |   7 - 0000000111
 10 - 0000001010  |   9 - 0000001001
 11 - 0000001011  |   7 - 0000000111
 12 - 0000001100  |  11 - 0000001011
 13 - 0000001101  |  11 - 0000001011
 14 - 0000001110  |  13 - 0000001101
 15 - 0000001111  |  -1 - 1111111111
 16 - 0000010000  |  15 - 0000001111
 17 - 0000010001  |  15 - 0000001111
 18 - 0000010010  |  17 - 0000010001
 19 - 0000010011  |  15 - 0000001111
 20 - 0000010100  |  19 - 0000010011
 21 - 0000010101  |  19 - 0000010011
 22 - 0000010110  |  21 - 0000010101
 23 - 0000010111  |  15 - 0000001111
 24 - 0000011000  |  23 - 0000010111
 25 - 0000011001  |  23 - 0000010111
 26 - 0000011010  |  25 - 0000011001
 27 - 0000011011  |  23 - 0000010111
 28 - 0000011100  |  27 - 0000011011
 29 - 0000011101  |  27 - 0000011011
 30 - 0000011110  |  29 - 0000011101
```

Comment: Try evaluating this expression for several different values of `i` and see for yourself. Hint: display both `i` and the result in binary.

Comment: ...which you could do with `std::cout << std::bitset<8>(i) << "\t" << std::bitset<8>((i & (i + 1)) - 1) << "\n";` if you keep `i` to 8 bits. In other words, it does something strange.

Comment: I guess its purpose is to test whether all bits are set (except for leading zeros) in which case `-1` is returned. Or in other words: `i & (i + 1) == 0`

Comment: From the context it looks like it navigates up the tree, and when you hit -1 you stop. So you could draw a graph of your output with every result = -1 as a root, and every other number a new node whose parent is the result.

Comment: and from Wikipedia it sounds like the intention here is to remove the least significant bit of the input, i.e. binary 1011 -> 1010, 1010 -> 1000. However it doesn't look like your code actually does that from your output.

Comment: @Rup no, the intention is to go to the next smaller index responsible for the sum.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. OK, but ["that parent is found by clearing the least-significant bit in the index"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree#Description). So it's the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the bit pattern of `i` is like `...0111`, the bit pattern of `i+1` will be `...1000`. Hence, `i & (i+1)` means `i - (2^{number of trailing ones} - 1)` and transforming all trailing `1`s to zero. For example if `i` is even, `i & (i+1)` will be equal to `i`. On the other hand, `-1` means, transforming all trailing zeros to `1` (including all trailing ones to zeros of the previous step) and transforming the successive `1`s to zeros.

By doing the `-1` for the next step, `i & (i+1)` will decrease the `i` by the `2^{number of trailing 1's}` of the previous value of the `i`.

What is the reason? It helps to show that the time complexity of finding the cumulative sum will be `O(log n)` in the worst case.

To find the reason behind this computation, you need to focus on each node `i` will responsible to compute index `i` to `(i - (1 << r)) + 1`. And "`r` represents the last 1 bit set in the index `i`". To find the total sum corresponding to index `i`, we need to sum all related values from `0` to `i`. Beware that we do not need to sum all indices because of the specified property. Hence, we need to sum indices `i`, `i - (1 << r)`, ... and so on so forth.

Comment: Thanks! I see now what it's supposed to do, but what does this mean in the context of the attached code?

Comment: @StackExchange123 Please see the updated answer (the last paragraph).

Comment: When you say "leading" I think you mean "trailing" throughout. Also, the `i - 2^[number of leading ones}` is off by one; `i & (i + 1)` is `i - 2^{number of trailing ones} + 1`.